How can I pause and reapply Shielding with a guard statement?
Im new to coding so sry for the inconvenience. So basically I have this project, so that when I hit the primary button of the shield configuration, that it sends a notification and also starts unshielding and then reshielding. however I implemented a guard In the unshield and reshield function so that the Button from the view where the notification leads to, needs to be pressed first and then the unshielding and reshielding process should start. At the moment only the notification works and nothing else gets executed after I hit the relevant button. Please help I have been trying to fix this for weeks...
        class TimerManager: ObservableObject {
            var isConfirmed = false
            static let shared = TimerManager()
            }
    struct SwiftUIView: View {
    let appToken: ApplicationToken
        private let timerManager = TimerManager.shared
    var body: some View {
    Button("Pause Shield for 5 Minutes") {
                    ButtonAction(for: appToken)
                }
    }
    private func ButtonAction(for appToken: ApplicationToken) {
            
            timerManager.isConfirmed = true
            
        }
    }
class ShieldActionExtension: ShieldActionDelegate {
    override func handle(action: ShieldAction, for application: ApplicationToken, completionHandler: @escaping (ShieldActionResponse) -> Void) {
        switch action {
        case .primaryButtonPressed:
            
            sendShieldNotification(for: application)
            attemptShieldModification(for: application)
            completionHandler(.none)
        case .secondaryButtonPressed:
            
            completionHandler(.none)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }
    
    func attemptShieldModification(for application: ApplicationToken) {
        let timerManager = TimerManager.shared
        // Guard: Ensure the action is confirmed before proceeding.
        guard timerManager.isConfirmed == true else {
            print("Action not confirmed. Exiting function.")
            return // Exit if not confirmed
        }

        // Proceed with unlock and reapply shield because the guard condition was met.
        unlockApp(for: application)
        reapplyShield(for: application)
        
        // Reset confirmation after successful operation.
        timerManager.isConfirmed = false
        print("Shield modification completed successfully.")
    }
}

I left some irrelevant stuff out. I currently have the target membership for the Timermanager for Main App and the shield action extension. I also have an app group which is shared between the main app and the shield action extension.
